# Would uncooked bacon go bad in a transatlantic flight?

Tags: air-travel, health, food-and-drink

I am going to have a transatlantic flight (Canada-Italy-Turkey) and would like to bring uncooked bacon with me (standard packaged bacon from a supermarket). I will be carrying it in my luggage that I check in.

Would it go bad during the travel (between the time I check in and get my luggage) or would there be any other issue with it? Especially at Italy where I make a connection.

Comment: @pnuts i know, it gets pretty much -50 celcius up there, my bigger concern is the time before and after the actual flight

Comment: What about vacuum packing?

Comment: It will survive. I would be more concerned as to whether you are allowed to import it into Turkey. Most countries have import restrictions on various meats, to reduce the spread of animal diseases.

Comment: @Alexander Not to mention that Turkey is an Islamic country and they are not so big on Pork there.

Comment: Turkey is a secular country, you can find pork products easily from supermarkets in Istanbul, like Migros, Macro, Real etc., but it might be harder in smaller towns due to lack of demand. Here is one from migros http://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/prview/1447656-30129-bonus-bacon-domuz-pastirmasi-80-gr

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com might also give you good advice; people there are probably more knowledgeable about food safety.

Comment: @Alexander they might have some restrictions but they seem to be very very flexible, they don't do any of the stuff(forms, checking the luggage etc.) they do in europe or north america

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have flown from the USA back to Asia with cured meat products (southern hog jowls) without issue.  I freeze them before I go, then wrap with some insulating materials.  It survives some 24 hours of traveling without a problem.

Usually at intermediate airports there is no health inspection, so there shouldn't be a problem in Italy (unless you have separate tickets that require rechecking bags in Italy)

Answer (score 13):

I doubt it will go bad. However, there might be other issues:

1. Most countries have import restrictions for food due to diseases. Technically, Turkey does not allow the import of meat, although I understand that they're quite flexible with that.
2. As a predominantly Muslim country, Bacon might raise some eyebrows in Turkey.

Answer (score 5):

Freeze it, and put some dry ice in the container. The dry ice will keep it cold a lot longer than just insulation.

Dry ice is usually ok on flights, but you do have to package it properly and tell the airline how many kilograms. The package basically has to allow the gas to vent - a styrofoam box not fully taped closed will be fine. And the weight is because there is a limit on the total amount of dry ice the plane can take. So they add yours up along with any others.