# Can I bring meat pies in my checked-in bags?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, food-and-drink, philippines, malaysia-airlines

I am going back to the Philippines for a short vacation and I was wondering if I could bring some meat pies from Australia.

I will be flying with Malaysia Airlines.

I have two questions :

1. Does Malaysia Airlines allow bringing food in checked-in baggage?
2. Will my food spoil or anything due to temperature, pressure, or whatever possible reason during flight?

Answer (score 4):

> Does Malaysia Airlines allow bringing food in the checked-in baggage?

Strictly speaking, it appears not. See last page of Malaysia Airlines [Baggage Information](http://www.malaysiaairlines.com/content/dam/malaysia-airlines/mas/PDF/Baggage-Information.pdf):

> Malaysia Airlines advises you that following items may not be included in your baggage and liability is limited under the applicable international Convention for your damage or loss.
>
> Cash, negotiable bonds, deed, etc; Jewellery, antiques or similar valuable items; Any item of a fragile or brittle nature (e.g. glassware); Electrical or electronic components (e.g. computer, camera, mobile phone, audio equipment); Food or any perishable item; Any item that has insufficient packaging (e.g. surfboard, bicycle, musical instrument)

However meat pies are not classified by them as dangerous goods (ibid) so I doubt the airline would mind - just does not accept responsibility for them.

> Will my food spoil or anything due to temperature, pressure, or whatever possible reason during flight?

There is advice about that here: [Would uncooked bacon go bad in a transatlantic flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39104/would-uncooked-bacon-go-bad-in-a-transatlantic-flight).

If the pies are destined to be cooked I'd take the risk, but not otherwise.

Comment: The concern is probably more that if you don't eat them before Australia, Australia is unlikely to let you bring in meat products :/

Comment: Ah yes, you're right.  I read it as 'to the Philippines...back to Australia'.

Comment: I deleted the Australia tag as it is unnecessary. Anyway, I will only be brining 1 case, which is like 4 pieces. It's going to be consumed there, for sure. :)